# Component inserted with tag name doesn't work

Tags: javascript, data-binding, mvvm, vue.js

I'm working on a component that will be inserted into the DOM with a tag name like so: `<component></component>` instead of the `v-component` directive. For some reason it's not working.

http://jsbin.com/yeyov/2/edit

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the tag name has a dash in it, like `<component-name></component-name>` or it will not work.

Fixed: http://jsbin.com/yeyov/3/edit